# Why %n need to use with care?

Tags: symbols, history

[image]

I am new to Mathematica and don't understand why %n need to use with care.

Is there any problem if use it?

I cannot find explanation [in the book](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingPreviousResults.html).

Comment: Which book is this?

Comment: @Szabolcs *The Mathematica Book*, 2nd ed., Sect 1.2.1 (p. 54).  Or the tutorial link I added.

Comment: Maybe you are not aware that code may be written in differents cells and that you don't necessary evaluate the cells in order. So %n is dependent of the order in which you have evaluated the cells. In particular, if you evaluate the same cell twice, the number of the "out" of the cell (out[number]) is changed.

Comment: that edit makes this question confusing. The post says "I cannot find explanation in .." <link to extremely clear explanation..>   @ChekWeiTan did you read that link, do you still have a question?

Comment: @george2079 That "explanation" is just below the examples that follow the table, both in the tutorial and in the book.  I assume that, in the OP's opinion, that paragraph is an insufficient explanation of why "care" is needed.  It basically isn't much more than an admonition to pay attention to the definition, which would apply to using any symbol. I interpret the question to come down to, Is there something particularly dangerous about `%n`? But maybe the answer is trivial, and what the book means is just what is in that paragraph...

Comment: ...I personally thought there might be some danger in reevaluating an output after the state of the session & kernel has changed.  But I haven't thought of a good example, if one exists.  But I'm pretty sure that has nailed me in past, even causing a crash.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's not clear. The cited [book](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingPreviousResults.html) reports
«[...] successive input and output lines need not appear in order.»

This means that you can have a situation like this:

```
Out[3]=1
Out[1]=0
Out[2]=0
```

if you just count the number of lines, you can think that the 3rd line corresponds to the 3rd output, but it's not true and you can make mistakes: for example the sum of the 2nd and 3rd line is not

```
%2 + %3 = 1
```

but

```
%1 + %2 = 0
```

Comment: this isn't really an answer is it?. What the link actually says is "Because you can insert and delete anywhere in a notebook, the textual ordering of results in a notebook need have no relation to the order in which the results were generated. " which seems pretty clear.